# Compatibility between Unity 5.6.1f1 and VS

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, installation

When you installed Visual Studio Community 2017, it installed Unity 5.6.0f3. However, the latest version is 5.6.1f1, my question is: is the latest version of Unity incompatible with VS 2017 or is it because when the VS 2017 was released the 5.6.0 was the latest version?

Is it safe to update Unity? If so, by the configuration on your site, or should I use VS to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes it's safe to update.

IDEs usually do not affect much, if not at all, in building projects. I believe different IDEs may have different `include paths` but in terms of project compilation it's mostly handled within Unity (i.e., IDEs do not matter much).

More often you will need to worry about updating your projects (your scripts and scripts in imported assets) when switching between different Unity versions, than IDEs. It is possible that the same functions or classes have subtle differences in their behaviours, or new (better) classes are introduced or obsolete classes are removed in newer Unity versions.

Even then, most of the times you do not need to worry much about different Unity versions when they have similar numbers. `5.6.0` and `5.6.1` have very minor differences, which are mainly improvements or bug fixes rather than introducing new features or removing old features. When the number changes to `5.6` from `5.5`, there can be certain changes you should check out. When the numbering changes to `Unity 5` from `Unity 4`, or to `Unity 2017.1` from `Unity 5.6`, you should (or must) save previous version, check the differences, and proceed to next versions carefully. When such major version changes occur, some programmers even choose not to update their Unity projects when the project size gets larger or the new features are not required for their projects.

If you wish to make sure what components are affected in different Unity verisons, you can always refer to the official [Unity change logs](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.1).

Also, whenever you are worried to have issues in changing versions for any related parts of your project -- whether it being your IDEs, Unity versions, Asset versions, platform supports, etc, it's good time to think about having backups or Version Control Systems like [git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git).